# How do I install mysql2 gem with percona 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, percona

I've setup `percona-server-server` and `percona-server-client` packages as per the [instructions on the percona website](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/installation/apt_repo.html), but when I try to install the mysql gem, I see the following message:

`Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

Looking in the logs I see:

```
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
```

I tried installing `libmysqlclient-dev`, but this installs the 5.5 version, and I see this error:

`Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.41 but the client library is 5.6.23-72.1.`

How do I install this properly?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `libmysqlclient-dev`, install [`libperconaserverclient18.1-dev`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/percona_server_with_xtradb/trusty/main/base/libperconaserverclient18.1-dev) and `libssl-dev` packages.

More info in this [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/604908/392290).